# How to send base64 image using Python requests and FastAPI?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests, base64, fastapi

I am trying to make a code for image style transfer based on FastAPI. I found it effective to convert the byte of the image into base64 and transmit it.

So, I designed my client codeto encode the image into a base64 string and send it to the server, which received it succesfully. However, I face some difficulties in restoring the image bytes to ndarray.

I get the following this errors:

```
image_array = np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(image_byte)).reshape(image_shape)

ValueError: cannot reshape array of size 524288 into shape (512,512,4)
```

This is my client code :

```
import base64
import requests
import numpy as np
import json
from matplotlib.pyplot import imread
from skimage.transform import resize


if __name__ == '__main__':
    path_to_img = "my image path"

    image = imread(path_to_img)
    image = resize(image, (512, 512))

    image_byte = base64.b64encode(image.tobytes())
    data = {"shape": image.shape, "image": image_byte.decode()}

    response = requests.get('http://127.0.0.1:8000/myapp/v1/filter/a', data=json.dumps(data))
```

and this is my server code:

```
import json
import base64
import uvicorn
import model_loader
import numpy as np

from fastapi import FastAPI
from typing import Optional


app = FastAPI()

@app.get("/")
def read_root():
    return {"Hello": "World"}


@app.get("/myapp/v1/filter/a")
async def style_transfer(data: dict):
    image_byte = data.get('image').encode()
    image_shape = tuple(data.get('shape'))
    image_array = np.frombuffer(base64.b64decode(image_byte)).reshape(image_shape)

if __name__ == '__main__':
    uvicorn.run(app, port='8000', host="127.0.0.1")
```

Comment: please check if your image have 16 bit color range - it seems suspicious that image have exactly 512*512*2 bytes = 2 bytes or 16 bits per pixel

Answer (score 5, accepted):

### Option 1

As previously mentioned [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request/70640522#70640522), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/64494731/requests-format-for-uploading-multiple-images-in-fastapi/70657469#70657469) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), one should use [`UploadFile`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/), in order to upload files from client apps (for `async` read/write have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70667530/17865804)). For example:

**server side:**

```py
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(file: UploadFile = File(...)):
    try:
        contents = file.file.read()
        with open(file.filename, 'wb') as f:
            f.write(contents)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
    finally:
        file.file.close()
        
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {file.filename}"}
```

**client side:**

```py
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
file = {'file': open('images/1.png', 'rb')}
resp = requests.post(url=url, files=file) 
print(resp.json())
```

### Option 2

If, however, you still need to send a `base64` encoded image, you can do it as previously described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70689003/17865804) (Option 2). On client side, you can encode the image to `base64` and send it using a `POST`  request as follows:

**client side:**

```
import base64
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/upload'
with open("photo.png", "rb") as image_file:
    encoded_string = base64.b64encode(image_file.read())
    
payload ={"filename": "photo.png", "filedata": encoded_string}
resp = requests.post(url=url, data=payload)
```

On server side you can receive the image using a [`Form`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-forms/) field, and decode the image as follows:

**server side:**

```py
@app.post("/upload")
def upload(filename: str = Form(...), filedata: str = Form(...)):
    image_as_bytes = str.encode(filedata)  # convert string to bytes
    img_recovered = base64.b64decode(image_as_bytes)  # decode base64string
    try:
        with open("uploaded_" + filename, "wb") as f:
            f.write(img_recovered)
    except Exception:
        return {"message": "There was an error uploading the file"}
        
    return {"message": f"Successfuly uploaded {filename}"}
```