# How to send multiple files with Python requests to FastAPI server?

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I have the following endpoint in my FastAPI server:

```
@app.post("/submit")
async def submit(file1: List[UploadFile] = File(...), file2: List[UploadFile] = File(...), file3: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    # do something
    return 'hello'
```

It works as expected if I use Swagger UI. However, I cannot figure out how to send a `POST` request to this endpoint using Python `requests` module. Here is what I've tried:

```
import requests

headers = {
    'accept': 'application/json',
    'Content-Type': 'multipart/form-data',
}

files = [
    ('file1', open('file1.zip', 'rb')), 
    ('file2', open('file2.txt', 'rb')),
    ('file3', open('file3.rar', 'rb')),
]

response = requests.post('http://localhost:8000/submit', headers=headers, files=files)

print(response.text)
```

But I am getting an error:

```
{"detail":"There was an error parsing the body"}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should either define each `file` as a separate parameter in the endpoint, e.g., `file1: UploadFile = File(...)`, `file2: UploadFile = File(...)`, etc. (without using `List`), or, preferably, define a `List` of files using `files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)`, as shown below (the below can be used to return the filenames of all uploaded files).

```
@app.post("/submit")
async def submitUPP(files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    # do something
    return {"Uploaded Files:": [file.filename for file in files]}
```

On client side, you should send the list of files using the same `key` you gave in the endpoint (i.e., `files` in the case above) for each file.

```
files = [
    ('files', open('file1.zip', 'rb')), 
    ('files', open('file2.txt', 'rb')),
    ('files', open('file3.rar', 'rb')),
]
```

You may also want to have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70711176/17865804) answer.

### Important

In addition to the above, one shouldn't set the `Content-Type` in the headers
to  `multipart/form-data` when using files, but rather let Python requests set the `Content-Type`, as in addition to `multipart/form-data`, `Content-Type` **must** include the [`boundary`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data) string used to separate each body part in the multipart payload). Please have a look at the answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399124/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804). Setting the `Content-Type` in the way you do is the reason for the error you encountered, i.e., `{'detail': 'There was an error parsing the body'}`. Thus, you should avoid setting the `Content-Type` in the headers.