# POST request to FastAPI using Python Requests with a file and query parameters

Tags: python, python-requests, fastapi

I am using FastAPI to serve some ML models and I have a `Streamlit` basic UI using Python `Requests` module.

One of my service is getting an image through a POST request and it is working like a charm.

**Server side**

```py
@app.post("/segformer")
async def segformer(file: Optional[UploadFile] = None):
```

**curl given by {BASE_URI}/docs**

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/segformer' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@image1.jpg;type=image/jpeg'
```

**Client side using Python Requests**

```
response = requests.post(f"{BASE_URI}/segformer", files=files)
```

As soon as I want to add additional parameters, it gets creepy. For example:

**Server side**

```py
@dataclass
class ModelInterface:
    model_name: str = "detr"
    tags: List[str] = Query(...)

@app.post("/detr")
async def detr(file: UploadFile = File(...), model: ModelInterface = Depends()):
```

**curl -- given by {BASE_URI}/docs**

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/detr?model_name=detr&tags=balloon&tags=dog' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@image1.jpg;type=image/jpeg'
```

Until that point everything works fine. Once I want to convert that call using Python `Requests`, I have some issues, which always end up in `/detr HTTP/1.1" 400 Bad Request` error.

Here is what I've tried:

**Client side using Python Requests**

```py
headers = {
    "Content-type": "multipart/form-data",
    "accept": "application/json"
}

payload = {
    "tags": ["balloon", "dog"]
}

response = requests.post(
    f"{BASE_URI}/detr",
    headers=headers,
    json=payload,  <- also *data*  
    files=files,
)
```

At the end it seems that the problem narrows on how to convert this:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/detr?tags=balloon&tags=dog' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@image1.jpg;type=image/jpeg'
```

to a valid Python `Requests` call!

I also faced the issue that the following FastAPI code:

```py
@dataclass
class ModelInterface:
    model_name: str = "detr"
    tags: List[str] = None

@app.post("/detr2")
async def detr2(file: UploadFile = File(...), model: ModelInterface = Form(...)):
...
```

translates to this `curl` command:

```
curl -X 'POST' \
  'http://localhost:8080/detr2' \
  -H 'accept: application/json' \
  -H 'Content-Type: multipart/form-data' \
  -F 'file=@image1.jpg;type=image/jpeg' \
  -F 'model={
  "model_name": "detr",
  "tags": [
    "balloon", "dog"
  ]
}'
```

which fails with a `"POST /detr2 HTTP/1.1" 422 Unprocessable Entity` error

Comment: Should your payload not also contain `model_name`?

Comment: I am assuming the default `model_name: str = "detr"` would be pick if not set - but I might be wrong !

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To pass query parameters in Python requests, you should use `params` key instead. Hence:

```py
response = requests.post(url='<your_url_here>', params=payload)
```

Additionally, there is no need to set the `Content-type` in the headers, as it will automatically be added, based on the parameters you pass to `requests.post()`. Doing so, the request will fail, as, in addition to `multipart/form-data`,"*`Content-type` **must** include the `boundary` value used to delineate the parts in the post body. Not setting the `Content-Type` header ensures that requests sets it to the correct value*" ([ref](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python#comment90652412_12385661)). Have a look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12385179/how-to-send-a-multipart-form-data-with-requests-in-python) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3508338/what-is-the-boundary-in-multipart-form-data). Also, make sure that in `files` you use the same `key` name you gave in your endpoint, i.e., `file`. Thus, in Python requests it should look something like the below:

```py
files = {('file', open('my_file.txt', 'rb'))}
response = requests.post(url='<your_url_here>', files=files, params=payload)
```

You could also find more options as to how to send additional data along with files at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/65504438/how-to-add-both-file-and-json-body-in-a-fastapi-post-request/70640522#70640522).