# How to pass string and multiple files using FastAPI and Python requests?

Tags: python, file-upload, python-requests, fastapi

I am using the following FastAPI endpoint that accepts multiple files:

```
from fastapi import Request, FastAPI, File, UploadFile
from typing import List
import uvicorn

app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/multiplefiles")
async def _file_upload(keywords, files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)): #create_file
    return {"len_files": keywords}
```

I would like to first input the `keywords` parameter, then the list of `files`, but I cannot find a way to perform a valid post request:

```
import requests

files = (("keywords", "key1"),
    [
    ('files', open('files\file1.pdf', 'rb')), 
    ('files', open('files\file2.pdf', 'rb'))
    ]
)

response = requests.post('http://127.0.0.1:3000/multiplefiles', files=files)
print(response.json())
```

If I only upload the `files` as a list of tuple work, but I do not know how to pass in the `keywords` parameter.

Comment: What is it that you want the requests library to do with the ("keywords", "key1") element?  I don't know FastAPI, so looking at the back end def doesn't help me really.

Comment: The keywords are searched in the files, but for the solution I am building I need to pass both keywords and the files with the same call

Answer (score 1, accepted):

### Option 1 -  Define query parameter as `str`

In the way the `keywords` parameter is defined in your endpoint is expected to be a `query` parameter. If you expect it to be a single string value, you can define it using `str` as follows:

**Server side:**

```py
@app.post("/")
def upload(keywords: str, files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    return {"keywords": keywords}
```

Since it is expected as query parameter, you should use the [`params` argument in Python requests](https://requests.readthedocs.io/en/latest/user/quickstart/#passing-parameters-in-urls), in order to pass query parameters, as described [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71399124/17865804). Example:

**Client side:**

```py
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
data = {'keywords': 'key1'}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, params=data)
print(r.json())
```

You could also pass it directly to the URL instead:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000?keywords=key1'
```

### Option 2 - Define query parameter as `List`

If you are sending a list of keywords, you have to declare the `keywords` query parameter with a type of `List` (or `list` in Python 3.9+), and define it [explicitly with `Query`](https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/query-params-str-validations/#query-parameter-list-multiple-values), so that it can receive a list of values, or in other words, to receive multiple values—see related answers [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71039241/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/72070110/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70845425/17865804) (for arbitrary query parameters see [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70840850/17865804) and [this](https://stackoverflow.com/a/73831142/17865804)). Example:

**Server side:**

```py
from fastapi import Query

@app.post("/")
def upload(keywords: List[str] = Query(...), files: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    return {"keywords": keywords}
```

**Client side:**

```py
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
data = {'keywords': ['key1', 'key2']}
r = requests.post(url, files=files, params=data)
print(r.json())
```

If you would like to add the list of `keywords` to the URL's query string yourself, it should then look like this:

```
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/?keywords=key1&keywords=key2'
```

See [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/71427592/17865804) for more details.

### Option 3 - Use `Form` parameters

If you would like to use `Form` parameters instead to pass additional data along with `files`, please have a look at [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70640522/17865804).