# How to POST multiple images to FastAPI server using Python requests?

Tags: python, request, fastapi

I would like to send multiple images to FastAPI backend using Python requests.

**Server side**

```
from fastapi import FastAPI, UploadFile, File
from typing import List
app = FastAPI()

@app.post("/")
def index(file: List[UploadFile] = File(...)):
    list_image = []
    for i in file:
        list_image.append(i.filename)
    return {"list_image": list_image}
```

**Client side**

Currently, I can only send a request with a single image. However, I would like to be able to send multiple images.

```
import requests
import cv2

frame = cv2.imread("../image/3.png")
imencoded = cv2.imencode(".jpg", frame)[1]
file = {'file': ('image.jpg', imencoded.tostring(),
                    'image/jpeg', {'Expires': '0'})}

response = requests.post("http://127.0.0.1:8000/", files=file)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You would need to pass the files/images as shown in the example below. See here and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657469/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804) for more details.

### Example

```
import requests

url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
files = [('file', open('images/1.png', 'rb')), ('file', open('images/2.png', 'rb'))]
resp = requests.post(url=url, files=files)
```

or, you could also use:

```
import requests
import glob

path = glob.glob("images/*", recursive=True) # images' path
files = [('file', open(img, 'rb')) for img in path]
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/'
resp = requests.post(url=url, files=files)
```