# File upload using FastAPI returns error 422

Tags: python, file-upload, fastapi, http-status-code-422

I am using the example from the official documentation: https://fastapi.tiangolo.com/tutorial/request-files/#import-file

Server code:

```
@app.post("/uploadfile")
async def create_upload_file(data: UploadFile = File(...)):
    print("> uploaded file:",data.filename)
    return {"filename": data.filename}
```

Client code:

```
files = {'upload_file': open('config.txt', 'rb')}
resp = requests.post(
        url = URL,
        files = files)
print(resp.json())
```

The problem is that the server always responds with error 422:

```
{'detail': [{'loc': ['body', 'data'], 'msg': 'field required', 'type': 'value_error.missing'}]}
```

I am using Python 3 on both server and client and the python-multipart package is already installed.

Can someone please tell me what I am doing wrong, what am I missing, how should I fix the code?

Any hints are much appreciated.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

On client side you should use the **same** name given for the parameter on server side, when adding the file. In your case, that parameter is called `data`, as shown below:

```py
@app.post('/uploadfile')
async def create_upload_file(data: UploadFile = File(...)):
                             ^^^^
```

Hence, you should **replace** `upload_file` with `data` on client side, as shown below:

```py
url = 'http://127.0.0.1:8000/uploadfile'
files = {'data': open('config.txt', 'rb')}
r = requests.post(url=url, files=files)
```

More details and examples on how to upload file(s) using Python requests and FastAPI can be found in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657621/17865804), as well as [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70657469/17865804), [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70641755/17865804) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/a/70711176/17865804).

Answer (score 3):

Well, I just realized my error (which is not immediately obvious for newbies like me :))

The parameter you pass on client side (`'upload_file'`)

```
files = {'upload_file': open('config.txt', 'rb')}
```

must match the parameter on the server side (`'data'`):

```
async def create_upload_file(data: UploadFile = File(...)):
```

So in order to work I had to rename on client side '`upload_file`' to '`data`':

```
files = {'data': open('config.txt', 'rb')} # renamed 'upload_file' to 'data'
```

That's it. Hopefully this helps some others as well.